# SQL: How to refer subexpression from WHERE in SELECT?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

all! I have Postgresql and query

```
SELECT
  complex_expression()
FROM
  t
WHERE
  complex_expression() != '';
```

Is there a way to write `complex_expression()` only once in query and then refer to it? Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from
( 
SELECT complex_expression() ce
FROM t
)
where ce != '';
```